# pandas get mean column name and extra string columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, mean

In pandas 0.18.1, python 2.7.6:

Imagine we have the following table:

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,FROM_MONTH,AREA
1,2015,1,200
1,2015,2,200
1,2015,3,200
1,2015,4,200
1,2015,5,200
1,2015,6,200
1,2015,7,200
1,2015,8,200
1,2015,9,200
1,2015,10,200
1,2015,11,200
1,2015,12,200
1,2016,1,100
1,2016,2,100
1,2016,3,100
1,2016,4,100
1,2016,5,100
1,2016,6,100
1,2016,7,100
1,2016,8,100
1,2016,9,100
1,2016,10,100
1,2016,11,100
1,2016,12,100
```

We are trying to get an calendar year average in the following format

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,TYPE,AREA
1,2015,A,200
1,2016,A,100
1,2015,B,200
1,2016,B,100
```

Note: TYPE is a string column for other information. Here we only have 2 types of 'TYPE':  'A' and 'B'

If we tried the following, the 'AREA' column name is missing, also the ID=1 only shows in the first case.

```
AREA_CY=df.groupby(['ID','FROM_YEAR'])['AREA'].mean()
```

it returns:

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,
1,2015,200
,2016,100
,2015,200
,2016,100
```

If we tried the following:

```
AREA_CY=df.groupby(['ID','FROM_YEAR'])['AREA'].mean(axis=1)
```

it returns:

```
TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [102]: x = df.groupby(['ID','FROM_YEAR'])['AREA'].mean().reset_index(name='AREA')

In [103]: y = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE':['A','B']})

In [104]: x
Out[104]:
   ID  FROM_YEAR  AREA
0   1       2015   200
1   1       2016   100

In [105]: y
Out[105]:
  TYPE
0    A
1    B

In [106]: x.assign(key=0).merge(y.assign(key=0), on='key').drop('key', 1)
Out[106]:
   ID  FROM_YEAR  AREA TYPE
0   1       2015   200    A
1   1       2015   200    B
2   1       2016   100    A
3   1       2016   100    B
```

Explanation:

Let's make a [cartesian product](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra) (AKA full outer join) of `x` and `y` DFs:

```
In [126]: x.assign(key=0)
Out[126]:
   ID  FROM_YEAR  AREA  key
0   1       2015   200    0
1   1       2016   100    0

In [127]: y.assign(key=0)
Out[127]:
  TYPE  key
0    A    0
1    B    0

In [128]: x.assign(key=0).merge(y.assign(key=0), on='key')
Out[128]:
   ID  FROM_YEAR  AREA  key TYPE
0   1       2015   200    0    A
1   1       2015   200    0    B
2   1       2016   100    0    A
3   1       2016   100    0    B
```

Comment: Thanks!  Would you mind to briefly explain this line? x.assign(key=0).merge(y.assign(key=0), on='key').drop('key', 1)

Comment: Thanks #MaxU for the clear explanation.  I also encounter another challenge when developing the code in this topic.  Could you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637395/python-pandas-calculate-averages-column-by-column

Comment: I totally agree!