# python pandas calculate averages column by column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

In pandas 0.18.1, python 2.7.6:

Imagine we have the following table:

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,FROM_MONTH,YEARMONTH,AREA,AREA2
1,2015,1,201501,200,100
1,2015,2,201502,200,100
1,2015,3,201503,200,100
1,2015,4,201504,200,100
1,2015,5,201505,200,100
1,2015,6,201506,200,100
1,2015,7,201507,200,100
1,2015,8,201508,200,100
1,2015,9,201509,200,100
1,2015,10,201510,200,100
1,2015,11,201511,200,100
1,2015,12,201512,200,100
1,2016,1,201601,100,200
1,2016,2,201602,100,200
1,2016,3,201603,100,200
1,2016,4,201604,100,200
1,2016,5,201605,100,200
1,2016,6,201606,100,200
1,2016,7,201607,100,200
1,2016,8,201608,100,200
1,2016,9,201609,100,200
1,2016,10,201610,100,200
1,2016,11,201611,100,200
1,2016,12,201612,100,200
```

Is there any way that we can do the same thing as the following MySQL query in python pandas (the merge function can probably work, but is there any way to avoid an expensive merge/ join in python pandas)?

```
SELECT 
ID,
FROM_YEAR,
'A' AS TYPE,
AVG(AREA) AS AREA,
AVG(AREA2) AS AREA2
 FROM table GROUP BY ID,FROM_YEAR

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
ID,
FROM_YEAR,
'B' AS TYPE,
AVG(AREA) AS AREA,
AVG(AREA2) AS AREA2
 FROM table GROUP BY ID,FROM_YEAR;
```

The goal here is to get an calendar year average of AREA and AREA2 columns in the following format:

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,TYPE,AREA,AREA2
1,2015,A,200,100
1,2016,A,100,200
1,2015,B,200,100
1,2016,B,100,200
```

Could any guru enlighten?

================================= One extended question =================

Thanks for the answer! I just encounter another question in a trailing 12 case:

Desired output:

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,FROM_MONTH,YEARMONTH,AREA,AREA2
1,2015,1,201501,NULL,NULL
1,2015,2,201502,NULL,NULL
1,2015,3,201503,NULL,NULL
1,2015,4,201504,NULL,NULL
1,2015,5,201505,NULL,NULL
1,2015,6,201506,NULL,NULL
1,2015,7,201507,NULL,NULL
1,2015,8,201508,NULL,NULL
1,2015,9,201509,NULL,NULL
1,2015,10,201510,NULL,NULL
1,2015,11,201511,NULL,NULL
1,2015,12,201512,200,100
```

the following code

```
agg=df.groupby(['ID','FROM_YEAR'])[['AREA','AREA2']].rolling(window=12).mean()
```

will only generate this result, where FROM_MONTH and YEARMONTH are missing.

```
ID,FROM_YEAR,AREA,AREA2
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,NULL,NULL
1,2015,200,100
```

Could anyone enlighten? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas.concat` here it only involves one aggregation and doesn't invoke the `merge/join` process:

```
agg = df.groupby(['ID', 'FROM_YEAR'], as_index=False)[["AREA", "AREA2"]].mean()

pd.concat([agg.assign(TYPE = t) for t in ["A", "B"]], ignore_index=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice usage of a list comprehension with `assign` and `concat` to get the type column here! +1

Comment: @pansen Thanks! Appreciate the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant answer, Psidom !  I have another question on how to add another column and update the question.  Could you enlighten?

Comment: One option to keep them is to set those columns as index. `df.set_index(['FROM_MONTH', 'YEARMONTH']).groupby(['ID','FROM_YEAR'])[['AREA','AREA2']].rolling(window=12).mean().reset_index()`